# Kendo Grid Image Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC4 and kendo UI Free version.From Kendo UI i am using Kendo grid.But image field can't show properly.For image path i used relative path from database like this ~/Images/SmallThumb/smallDPP.png url

This is my field code

{
             field: "ProfilePicture.SmallThumbImageUrl",
             title: "Icon",
             template: ''
}

i think ~/ is main problem.when i remove ~/ works fine.So how can i show image form database using  this ~/Images/SmallThumb/smallDPP.png url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client side code doesn't know what `~` is since that's a .NET server-side "short cut" for the application root.  You would need to resolve the full path on the server side before sending down to the client.